# Use .html not .shtml for Server Side Includes on Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, ssi, azure-web-app-service

I would like to enable SSI on an Azure Web Site to but using .html rather than .shtml. SSI is enabled but for the life of me I can't find a way to get it to process .html.

Locally I've added a handler to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
    <add name="ASPClassicHtml" path="*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%IIS_BIN%\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And that works fine, but when I upload to the azure web site my i get the following error;

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment but SSI module inclusion on WAWS is apparently in the pipe-line.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/391a7918-00e8-49af-b2db-675980aebbd0